# nested RecyclerView with SortedList shows nothing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sortedlist

I have a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) nested in a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) and the adapter uses a [SortedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html) to hold the content.

This is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        marginTop="@{StatusbarUtils.getTopMargin(context)}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- some more ui elements -->

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_settings_cameras"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <!-- some more ui elements -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And my adapter:

```
public class SettingsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @NonNull private final SortedList<Camera> cameras;

    public SettingsRecyclerViewAdapter(@NonNull final OnSettingsInteractionListener listener) {
        cameras = new SortedList<>(Camera.class, new CameraSortedListCallback(this));
    }

    public void addCamera(@NonNull final Camera camera) {
        cameras.add(camera);
    }

    private static class CameraSortedListCallback extends SortedListAdapterCallback<Camera> {

        private final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

        CameraSortedListCallback(final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
            super(adapter);
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(final Camera o1, final Camera o2) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(final Camera oldItem, final Camera newItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(final Camera item1, final Camera item2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And how I uses it:

```
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    linearLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);

    adapter = new SettingsRecyclerViewAdapter(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I use it and call `addCamera(...)` nothing happens :-(

The `SortedListAdapterCallback` has a `onInserted` method which calls `mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count)`. When I override it and add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the RecyclerView shows the items.

```
    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
        Timber.i("onInserted() called with: " + "position = " + position + ", count = " + count);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onInserted(position, count);
    }
```

Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the `setHasFixedSize(true)` call (default is false). If this is true, the `recyclerview` thinks its size doesn't change when you notify him, but this is not the case here ;)

Hope this helps